# Partnerships and counting

Tags: combinatorics

If there are $2n$ people, then the number of ways to form partnerships of $2$ if order doesn't matter is given by $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$. I understood the story proof given here [Combinatorics: Partnerships Problem Overcounting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313406/combinatorics-partnerships-problem-overcounting) but I don't understand how to answer it using the combinatorics formula $nC2$. For example, the first thing that comes to my mind to approach this problem is to compute the number of ways to choose $2$ people out of $2n$ which is given by $(2n)C_2$. How to proceed from there? If that is not the right approach, why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $n$ pairs. For the first, choose $2$ out of $2n$, $\binom{2n}{2}$. For the second, choose $2$ out of remaining $2n-2$, $\binom{2n}{2}$. And so on to obtain n pairs $\binom{2n}{2}\binom{2n-2}{2}...\binom{2}{2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$

and do not forget to divide by $n!$ to cancel out permutation of $n$ pairs, $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}n!}$

Comment: Thanks, that helps! I'm wondering how is this problem different from the following problem: 'If there are $2n$ people in the room and each person shakes hand with every other person exactly once, how many handshakes take place?'. These two problems are fundamentally the same and yet for the handshake problem we stop at $(2n)C_2$. Why is that?

Comment: @ForumWhiner You can think of it as choosing only one pair; the pair doing handshake.

Comment: Great. Thanks a ton!

Comment: On an unrelated note, I just came to know that the even moments of a Standard normal distribution is also given by $(2n)!/(2^n n!)$. My mind is blown!